# Can Anyone Complete this regex?

Tags: asp.net, regex, regex-negation

```
KELECTRIC.BNK.20160526
```

compare above expression and take 8 digits after 2nd full stop and total of 22 characters,

below expression is working fine till 2nd full stop but not taking number after full stop

```
^(KELECTRIC)\.(BNK)+\.$
```

Comment: `^(KELECTRIC)\.(BNK)\.([0-9]{8})$`

Comment: thanks working fine :)

Comment: little modified :--  ^KELECTRIC\.BNK\.\K([0-9]{8})$

Answer (score 2):

You can accept number of 8 digits after 2nd full stop like this

```
^(KELECTRIC)\.(BNK)\.(\d{8})$
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better with (\d{8}) so you can get the number from one group instead of 8?

Comment: I think both are same. I have checked and both are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try `^(KELECTRIC)\.(BNK)\.[0-9]{8}$` or `^([A-Z]{1,})\.([A-Z]{1,})\.[0-9]{8}$`

Answer (score 0):

```
^(KELECTRIC)\.(BNK)\.([0-9]{8})$
```

this one answered by Kuba Wyrostek, and some other guys

thanks

Comment: It will accept every character at position where only `.` can come. You should use `\.` instead. `KELECTRIC-BNK-20160526` will also be a valid string for this.

Comment: This is equivalent to answer by @MHassan, so it is better to accept his answer instead of writing your own.